# DNS configuration for external/internal resolution

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, website

HI,

We have an internal web server which is available through Internet and from local network. The server is located in the local network.

The current configuration is the following:

- To access through Internet you use http://webexample.com
- To access through Local Network you use http://myweb

The main problem is that the local users cannot share links with external users. Thats a problem for us.

I want to setup the following configuration:

- All users (local and Internet) access through http://webexample.com
- The local DNS server resolves http://webexample.com to the local Network IP (i.e 192.168.2.100)

Any other suggestion? Which is the best way to override http://webexample.com resolution in Windows Server? It can be done on DNS server or it have to be done in `hosts` file?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to mess with DNS. You can tune your gateway.
[10. Destination NAT Onto the Same Network](http://netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-10.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done from the internal DNS server. But, please be very caution about the change, the reason to it is the fact that you might have some other systems talking to hosts at webexample.com zone.
Inspect the webexample.com external zone, copy all the appropriate records from the zone, create a new zone in your INTERNAL DNS server, copy the records to it, you will be required to decide which IP to use, will it be an external IP or internal.
Instruct your users to use the new links as required.

Comment: As I understand, I have to copy by hand all the DNS entries for webexample.com sub-domains , is that right?

Comment: Yep. That's correct.

Comment: There should be a better way to overide a single host in windows server dns

Comment: Such as ...? Example please

Comment: I agree with JorgeO - there ought to be a system where the internal DNS is told where the primary/authoritative server is for the zone, and can then be configured with only some domains for internal IPs (instead of having to configure all domains in the whole zone in two places) - unfortunately, you do seem to be stuck with having copies (with selected variances) of the complete zone in two places.

Answer (score 0):

If webexample.com is also your AD domain name this will be an overcomplicated configuration.  I would recommend as the easiest fix to setup www.webexample.com internally and externally and have everyone use that.  If webexample.com is your AD domain name just create a new DNS A record for www, pointing to the webserver.